# Ruby 6.1 with Nginx - restrict direct access to specific files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rails-activestorage

I am using Nginx server with a RoR webapplication (version 6.1.4).

I have several audio files around the site and I want to restrict direct access to them.
The page have publicly accessible part and another for registered members. Here they can upload and share mp3's through the platform.

I added the following lines to nginx configuration:

```
location ~* \.mp3 {
  valid_referers server_names;
  if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
  }
}
```

This one is working fine for the hardcoded audios and prevents direct access.

But if someone logs in and traces the html for the sourcefiles of uploaded audios, it is still accessible for them. I am using ActiveStorage for managing file uploads and it is on a s3 storage.

Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: so you want to restrict unauthenticated users to download your files? What is difference between authenticated and unauthenticated user? Cookie presence? Then check for cookie or another sign that user was authenticated.

Comment: I am using devise for authentication. So unauthenticated users (aka unregistered ones) cannot access those files. I am looking for a solution to prevent direct access and download of the authenticated users. They should be only able to interact with the files through the portal and not downloading the files.

Answer (score 0):

Did not check, but customize this and try:

```
location ~* \.mp3 { # location for .mp3 files
    if (-f $request_filename) { # if file actually exists
       return 301 $scheme://$server_name/RoR_APP_URI_with_auth_check/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really get how should a permanent redirect help me with the situation. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @hecsaber my idea is to force users to do to your RoR controller to check their credentials

Comment: maybe I was not completely clear, but I am looking for a solution where I can prevent already authenticated users to directly access and download the files, (but being able to interact with them only through the app). Preventing unauthenticated access is solved already!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good opportunity to use the Proxy design pattern. You could create a controller/action that handles user authentication and then either redirects to the appropriate url or directly serves the file using `send_file`. There are pro's and con's to this approach but it would be a way to authenticate requests and restrict access to paywalled content.

Here's an example from a production app I'm working on:

```
  def avatar_proxy
    if Rails.env.development?
      tmp_file = open(current_user.avatar.path)
    else
      url = current_user.avatar.url
      tmp_file = open(url)
    end
    send_file tmp_file, :type => current_user.avatar.content_type, disposition: 'inline'
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try and get back to you!